# ORA0001: Unique Contraint causing web application shutdown

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

Has anyone run across this?

An Oracle ORA0001: Unique Constraint violation originating from a JMX endpoint is causing an instance of my deployed application (Tomcat) to shutdown.

I have looked online but do not see anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the stack trace show an SQLException bubbling all the way up to Tomcat; or maybe the SQLException is being caught and rethrown as a runtime exception or error? Hard to begin to guess without seeing the stack trace...

Comment: The exception "java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (EMPLOYEE.PK_EMPLOYEE_ID) violated" is being wrapped by Spring as DuplicateKeyException.

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace? Does the Tomcat server log have a stack trace before it shuts down?